# Pperforming trilateration using 3 lat/lon points without distances

Tags: distance, geodesy

I read [Trilateration using 3 latitude/longitude points, and 3 distances?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances/415#415) explaining about trilateration using 3 latitude and longitude with measured distance.

The problem is I want to find out an unknown target location with only 3 knowns latitude and longitude co-ordinates **without knowing each distance point**. For example, I have 3 following longitudes and latitudes:

> lat="-6.28530175" lon="106.9004975375" 
> lat="-6.28955287" lon="106.89573839" 
> lat="-6.28388865789474" lon="106.908087643421"

---

Based on @D.E.Wright answer I am googling to find out more and I get this following forum http://www.coderanch.com/t/453432/Programming/implement-cell-triangulation-mobile-phones, it gives 3 steps to triangulation. The problem I couldn't understand what he means about "Calculate distance from the first tower based on speed which gives a radius value". 
 And with @Kirk Kuykendall suggestion I decide to put my 3 lat/long to google map and I get this following image :

[image: Google Maps]

Where : 
A, B, C : Cell Towers location

A : lat **-6.28955287**, lon **106.89573839** with cell tower Radius **6000m** 
B : lat **-6.28530175**, lon **106.9004975375** with cell tower Radius **6000m**, and 
C : lat **-6.28388865789474**, lon **106.908087643421** with cell tower Radius **6000m**

Now, with these data can I doing a triangulation to get my real position and how is the mathematical method?

I've tried to modify Python code to remove the distance variable from @wwnick in [Trilateration using 3 latitude/longitude points, and 3 distances?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances/415#415) but until now I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree that I don't see how to get exact location without a distance. You would be in this situation:

[image]

So you would only be able to tell within a certain area where you were. And that's with only a 1000m buffer (radius). Your 6000m buffer has such an overlap that the potential location would be huge.

The solutions would be to:

1. Get some sort of distance measurement (even if it's approximate)
2. Use more cell towers
3. Use better placed cell towers

By better placed cell towers I mean that these three form a very flat triangle.
A more equilateral triangle would give smaller areas of overlap, meaning a more accurate position.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will have you doing concentric circles radiating out from each point; when all three intersect you will have our point. So you may have one radius of 15 miles, one of 10 miles and one of 25 miles, but at a point in space all three will intersect of have a mean point to intersect that will represent you originating point.
In EMS we use this triangulation method from Cell Towers a lot; but its programatic from our side since a cell signal doesn't give your range or bearing you need to use triangulation.