# Trilateration 3D - Vincenty's Formula

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, trilateration

with reference to [Trilateration using 3 latitude and longitude points, and 3 distances](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances).

The accepted answer was votes as shown in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration)  in conjunction with a conversion to radians before and after.

Is there a way to incorporate [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae)  to this process to bring a more accurate answer?

Comment: Over the sort of distances in the original question, its unlikely to make any kind of significant distance. Can you tell us more about your specific situation?

Answer (score 1):

For a discussion of various problems in ellipsoidal trigonometry, see Sections 10 and 11 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1215

Some similar problems are also discussed in
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z