# Trilateration using 3 x,y points and 3 distances, all in cm

Tags: python, distance, trilateration

I want to find out the position (x,y) of a given point, knowing the distance from 3 x,y points.

Below you can view the x,y coordinates and their given distances in **cm**.

```
B1x = 795
B1y = 332
B1d = 245.735630302

B2x = 795
B2y = 569
B2d = 327.946642001

B3x = 516
B3y = 569
B3d = 220.635445928
```

I have had a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/66), but this is for earth, and I get the error:

`z = math.sqrt(pow(DistA,2) - pow(x,2) - pow(y,2))
ValueError: math domain error`

**FIXED** the above error with `abs` to allow negative numbers but getting the wrong coordinates.

I want my algorithm to calculate in a 2D environment, with the given values above.

Here is the map:

You can see the **green X**, is where I want to locate, from the three given beacons (x,y) locations.

[image]

Comment: there are too many possibilities for us to interpolate here. what software, what output, what coordinate system. If it is just the math you want solved you should go to SE for that answer.