# Set of intersection points in trilateration / multilateration

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, geolocation, geodesy, trilateration

Like in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances) I will get a set of points (3 or more) with latitude, longitude and distance (in KM) information to find out the target location. A distance could be about 500 KM. The circles (unlike the above question) doesn't intersect in the same point which results in a set of points forming a region of a possible location.

Based on [this explanation](http://www.benfrederickson.com/calculating-the-intersection-of-3-or-more-circles/), I managed to write a java function that returns the set of intersection points for a set of circles (x,y,radius in CM) in the Cartesian coordinate system. But I don't know if I can adapt this function to get the intersection points of circles on the earth. Is this possible?