# Trilateration using latitude/longitude points, and distances

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gps, matlab, trilateration

I want to find out an unknown target location (latitude and longitude co-ordinates). There are +3 lat-long known points and for each point a distance in meters to the target location. I found some code on internet like [this](https://appelsiini.net/2017/trilateration-with-n-points/), [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57218-2d-trilateration) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-longitude-points-and-3-distances) but when I put my coordinates it gives this error which I couldn't solve.

> z = numpy.sqrt(pow(DistA,2) - pow(x,2) - pow(y,2))
>
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt

the coordinates are
(lat, lon, radius(m))

```
40.222167, 28.871361, 50
40.22175,  28.87169, 50
40.222528, 28.872083, 50
```

[image]

Could the error be due to location difference?

Comment: The square root of a negative number is *imaginary*.

Comment: @Vince Yes you're right but how can I solve this problem, why the result is negative? the coordinates that used in the codes I mentioned don't give negative result.

Comment: You haven't provided the values of your variables, but the only way to generate that error is a negative value.

Comment: @Vince the values are the coordinates and radius I wrote above

Comment: Your code has `DistA`, `x`, and `y`, and your data has lat, lon, and radius. Try printing the contents of the variables before executing the square root.